# Suppression State Error NU1101 Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages, dotnet-httpclient

[image]

I am new in dotnet razor website building platform visual studio 2022 . I tried to make my first website but it's show error according to following picture.
it's show below  errors:::

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddDbContext' and no accessible extension method 'AddDbContext'
> accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   project2    E:\Dontnet\project2\project2\Program.cs 9   Active
> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not
> exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly
> reference?)   project2    E:\Dontnet\project2\project2\Program.cs 2   Active
> Error CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter' and no accessible extension
> method 'AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter' accepting a first
> argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   project2    E:\Dontnet\project2\project2\Program.cs 11  Active
> Error CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddDefaultIdentity' and no accessible extension method
> 'AddDefaultIdentity' accepting a first argument of type
> 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly
> reference?)   project2    E:\Dontnet\project2\project2\Program.cs 13  Active
> Error CS1061  'WebApplication' does not contain a definition for
> 'UseMigrationsEndPoint' and no accessible extension method
> 'UseMigrationsEndPoint' accepting a first argument of type
> 'WebApplication' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly
> reference?)   project2    E:\Dontnet\project2\project2\Program.cs 22  Active
> Error NU1101  Unable to find package
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. No packages exist with this
> id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline
> Packages  project2    E:\Dontnet\project2\project2\project2.csproj    1
> Error NU1101  Unable to find package
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore. No packages exist
> with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline
> Packages  project2    E:\Dontnet\project2\project2\project2.csproj    1
> Error NU1101  Unable to find package
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore. No packages
> exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline
> Packages  project2    E:\Dontnet\project2\project2\project2.csproj    1
> Error NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.
> No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio
> Offline
> Packages  project2    E:\Dontnet\project2\project2\project2.csproj    1
> Error NU1101  Unable to find package
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools. No packages exist with this id in
> source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline
> Packages  project2    E:\Dontnet\project2\project2\project2.csproj    1

how can i solve this problem. i tried it to solve in many ways through internet and my course instructor but can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default template of Asp.net core- Razor pages with "individual accounts". Normally if you try run the project, it will auto restore the dependency packages, then the error should disappear.
[image]
You could try open the CMD console in the project directory and execute `dotnet restore` to restore the dependencies manually.